# django javascript does not working

Tags: javascript, python, django

When the gray div is clicked I want the website to be opened in a new tab, but here this javascript code isn't working. Why? How I can edit it?

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#gray").click(function(){
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='gray' style="width:100px;height:100px;background:gray;"></div>
</body>
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from secondv.views import test

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test', test),
]
```

The `jquery.min.js` file is in the template directory, the same directory as test.html file.

Comment: Side note : you haven't used ending script tag `</script>`.

Comment: modern browsers prevent javascript from opening new windows.

Comment: Is so, how can I open a website within a new tab by clicking on an image?

Comment: It's not working having the ending script tag added ? It's working fine in my browser, Chrome v 44.

Comment: Yes. My browser is Firefox 44.0.2  so no way?!

Comment: Check if jquery is loaded using console. Apparently, the problem is the way you are loading static file, i.e. jquery, in template. Read this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

Comment: try: `window.location.href`

Comment: @Mehran, have you set your static directory andplaced the js file there?

Comment: Yes, i've done the steps explained in doc (the link i gave in the comment above). Do as doc says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template directory is only for templates. All static content such as js, images should be placed to static directory. It's well described in docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/ - for production